# Kotlin expect generic subclass as parameter

Tags: kotlin, generics

I have an interface which contains a generic and have its extensions working properly, however I'm not able to receive a list of this subclasses as parameter.

The code below works perfectly:

```kotlin
interface Runnable

class FirstRunnable : Runnable
class SecondRunnable : Runnable

interface Runner<in T> where T : Runnable {
    fun run(runnable: T)
}

class FirstRunner : Runner<FirstRunnable> {
    override fun run(runnable: FirstRunnable) = println("first runner")
}

class SecondRunner : Runner<SecondRunnable> {
    override fun run(runnable: SecondRunnable) = println("second runner")
}
```

The problem comes in the block below:

```kotlin
class ListRunner(private val runners: List<Runner<Runnable>>)

val runner = ListRunner(listOf(FirstRunner(), SecondRunner()))
```

ListRunner does not accept `FirstRunner()` and `SecondRunner()` as parameters and complains with:

```
Type mismatch.
  Required:
    List<Runner<Runnable>
  Found:
    List<Runner<{FirstRunnable & SecondRunnable}>>
```

I want to inject the list into the `ListRunner` to be able to run in the entire list at once, within the runner I have a rule to run only accepted `Runnable`

---

**Solution**

Both answers helped me to find out the solution,

As pointed by [Nishant Jalan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11292068/nishant-jalan), I had first to add `out` variance to the `ListRunner`

```kotlin
class ListRunner(private val runners: List<Runner<out Runnable>>)
```

And as [Sweeper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5133585/sweeper) says:

> It is not safe to put anything there. The Kotlin type system is smart
> enough that it tells you this by saying that run there takes the type
> Nothing.

So the solution was adding `@UnsafeVariance` annotation to the `Runner` interface:

```kotlin
interface Runner<in T> where T : Runnable {
    fun run(runnable: @UnsafeVariance T)
}
```

Still it is unsafe and the annotation only prevents the compiler to complain about it, however I have a previous verification which guarantee the runnable is run in the correct runner.

Comment: Upon adding `@UnsafeVariance`, you might as well remove the generics altogether because they aren’t achieving anything for you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a star-projection to say you want a list of any kind of `Runner`:

```
class ListRunner(private val runners: List<Runner<*>>)
```

This will cause the following to compile:

```
val runner = ListRunner(listOf(FirstRunner(), SecondRunner()))
```

However, this will also prevent you from `run`ning any of the `runners` in `ListRunner`. For example, you cannot do this in `ListRunner`:

```
fun runAll() {
    for (runner in runners) {
        runner.run(...)
    }
}
```

Because *what actually is* the `...` part? It is not safe to put anything there. The Kotlin type system is smart enough that it tells you this by saying that `run` there takes the type `Nothing`.

You can't pass a `FirstRunnable`, because `runner` could be a `SecondRunner`, which takes a `SecondRunnable`. You can apply a similar reasoning for why you can't pass a `SecondRunnable`, or any other `Runnable`. `ListRunner` *don't know* what kind of `Runner`s are in the list, so it can't run it, because different `Runner`s needs different `Runnable`s to run.

Of course, you can check the types of the `runner` first, then give them the correct kind of runnable:

```
for (runner in runners) {
    when (runner) {
        is FirstRunner -> runner.run(FirstRunnable())
        is SecondRunner -> runner.run(SecondRunnable())
        else -> println("I didn't expect this type of runner!")
    }
}
```

Note that you need an `else` branch, in case someone passed in a `Runner` that isn't any of the types you are checking. Anyone can implement your interface, after all!

If you want to eliminate the `else` branch, you can make `Runner` sealed:

```
sealed interface Runner<in T> where T : Runnable {
```

Comment: Thank Sweeper, you answer helped me to find out the solution by adding @UnsafeVariance annotation

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things you can tweak in your code to perform the operation that you are looking for.

1. `interface Runner<in T> where T : Runnable` can simply be reduced to `interface Runner<T : Runnable>`. They both do the same thing.
2. While declaring the `ListRunner` class, you need to pass a List of Runner of a type that **is a** Runnable. Hence, you need to replace your type with `List<Runner<out Runnable>>`

The final code is written below.

```kotlin
interface Runnable

class FirstRunnable : Runnable
class SecondRunnable : Runnable

interface Runner<T : Runnable> {
    fun run(runnable: T)
}

class FirstRunner : Runner<FirstRunnable> {
    override fun run(runnable: FirstRunnable) = println("first runner")
}

class SecondRunner : Runner<SecondRunnable> {
    override fun run(runnable: SecondRunnable) = println("second runner")
}

class ListRunner(private val runners: List<Runner<out Runnable>>)
```

Comment: Thank Nishant Jalan, you answer helped me to find out the solution by addint out variance to the ListRunner

Comment: You are most welcome. do mark my answer has the solution if you found it helpful.